# Gem5 FS mode, changed the TimingSimpleCPU to O3CPU, the same script cannot run

Tags: gem5, node.js-fs

I just used the Gem5 in the FS mode, and I want to run my application through '--script' option and 'm5 readfile'. The problem is I can run my script in TimingSimpleCPU, but when I upgrade it into O3CPU, something go wrong! for example:

**in the gem5：**

```
build/X86/gem5.opt -d ./test-checkpoint/2core/256 configs/example/fs.py --disk=gapbs.img --kernel=vmlinux-4.8.13.gadia -n 2 --mem-size=512MB --script=./configs/boot/smp.rcS -r 1 --checkpoint-dir=./test-checkpoint/2core/ --restore-with-cpu=DerivO3CPU --cpu-type=DerivO3CPU --caches
```

**in the m5：**

```
sh -c 'm5 readfile > /tmp/gem5.sh && sh /tmp/gem5.sh 1 256 0'
```

**the script ran successfully！**

**in the gem5**

```
build/X86/gem5.opt -d ./test-checkpoint/2core/256 configs/example/fs.py --disk=gapbs.img --kernel=vmlinux-4.8.13.gadia -n 2 --mem-size=512MB --script=./configs/boot/smp.rcS -r 1 --checkpoint-dir=./test-checkpoint/2core/ --restore-with-cpu=DerivO3CPU --cpu-type=DerivO3CPU --caches
```

**in the m5：**

```
sh -c 'm5 readfile > /tmp/gem5.sh && sh /tmp/gem5.sh 1 256 0'
```

**The error are as follws：**

```
EXT4-fs error (device hda1): ext4_lookup:1609: inode #135500: comm sh: deleted inode referenced: 10677
Aborting journal on device hda1-8.
EXT4-fs (hda1): Remounting filesystem read-only
/tmp/gem5.sh: 15: /tmp/gem5.sh: ./SMP_1: Structure needs cleaning
```

I don't know what's the matter, I cannot figure it. Sorry for my poor English, thank you very much!

Why did I change the CPU type from TimingSimpleCPU to O3CPU, it will go wrong? And what's the problem here? How can I deal with it? Thanks!!!

Comment: The error you are getting is ambiguous. Can you try playing with your sys configuration. For example, if you don’t have enough memory resources, your kernel will be loaded in read-only mode. Consider allocating more memory and tell me what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but actually, I believe I have enough memory resources (256G memory size, 20 cores), and gem5 can only work on single core. I think it's very strange, just you know I remount my files into the .img file system, and it run successfully, I used the same command just I used before, so could you tell me how do you mount your file in FS mode. oh, and my gem5 version is 20.0.0.3, whihc is pretty  low compared with current open source (22.X)

Comment: what's more, the reason why I used the following command: 
 sh -c 'm5 readfile > /tmp/gem5.sh && sh /tmp/gem5.sh 1 256 0'
just because I cannot make checkpoint successfully, after my experimenta, I found that it can make it sometimes, I don't know what's wrong with it. I guess maybe my version is too low, and gem5 has some bugs I didn't get it. I made the checkpoint used the following command:

Comment: build/X86/gem5.opt -d ./test-checkpoint/2core/256 configs/example/fs.py --disk=gapbs.img --kernel=vmlinux-4.8.13.gadia -n 2 --mem-size=512MB --script=./configs/boot/hack_back_ckpt.rcS

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I am looking into it for you. It doesn’t sound like a trivial task to solve but I will keep you updated if I find something. The problem is that it’s kind of hard to debug with actually using your code. Let me see what I can do and will get back to you soon hopefully.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness! Sorry for the delay, recently I'm busy with my graduation, looking forward to your good news! If I get something new I will share with you, thanks!

Comment: I failed to regenerate the problem. I am sorry if I couldn’t have been any helpful here. Congrats on your graduation. I am graduating this summer. Wish me luck 

Comment: What a coincidence! Congratulations！